# How can I count "Checkboxes" in only Page1 in the UserForm1?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, userform

How can I count  "Checkboxes" only in Page1 in the UserForm1 with VBA?
Mine here below counts all in Page2 and Page3. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cnt As Integer
    cnt = Count.CheckBox()
    If Me.MultiPage1.Enabled = True Then
        Dim ctrl As msforms.Control, cnt As Long    
        cnt = 0
        For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.CheckBox Then
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox cnt
     End If
```

Answer (score 4):

You will find them here:

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls
```

If you just want the number:

```
MsgBox Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Count
```

**UPDATE**
Now actually counting the checkboxes

```
For Each ctrl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Is that all?  I didn't know the word of the "checkbox" can be deleted in the code. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly, beaten me to it. However if you just want to count checkboxes you will have to loop through the controls on your page and check if Typename(ctl) = “Checkbox”

Comment: Oops. Update coming. Thanks!

Comment: Could you also give me an advice using "IF" statement?  If I want on only select, I want to only count checkboxes in Page1.  The one below still  works when I am selecting "Page2".      If Me.MultiPage1..Pages(0).Enabled = True Then     
      cnt = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Count       
MsgBox cnt
       End If

Comment: Thank you,It worked. I wonder why it is not "Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1"

Comment: Unlike most VBA controls, the MultiPage control’s indices are 0-based. It’s peculiar...